# Temperature difference of thermoelastic bodies

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, elasticity, heat-conduction

- Let $B$ be a "very thin" tridimensional deformable body of the form below.

[image]

- Let $T_0$ be the temperature of $B$ in the reference state.
- Let $T(x,y,z)$ be the temperature at a point $(x,y,z)$ of the deformed state.
- Let $\Delta T=T(x,y,z)-T_0$ be the temperature difference.

**Question:** What are the physical (and/or mathematical) reasons we could use to justify the assertion below?

> As $B$ is very thin, we may take $\Delta T$ to satisfy $\Delta T=\theta_1(x)+y\theta_2(x)+z\theta_3(x)$ ([Lagnese](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mma.1670160503), p. 337).

Comment: What is the question here? Do you want to calculate the deflation due to heating or the temperature change due to deformation?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I want to understand why $\Delta T$ have the form $\Delta T=\theta_1(x)+y\theta_2(x)+z\theta_3(x)$.

Comment: This is a Taylor series expansion. Since y and z are small, only the first (linear) terms can be retained.